# Dehydrating in a convection oven

Tags: food-preservation, dehydrating

How do I use the oven to dehydrate foods. Do I close the door or leave it open?

Answer (score 1):

I usually turn it on the lowest it can go, and leave the door closed. I also watch whatever I'm drying very, very closely, because in a convection oven things move quite quickly. I do notice more even drying with a convection oven.

Comment: I agree. The fan will definitely promote more even drying. You definitely want to use the lowest possible setting - 170F, or even 150F. 200F may start to "cook" your food, rather than drying it. If you can't go any lower than 200F, you need to watch it **REALLY** carefully.